# 404 pages not working for Blog channel - but do for everything else

Tags: 404

I have just taken on an Expression Engine site (my first time with EE) and I am experiencing a strange issue.

We have a custom 404 error page which is working across the site except for on the blog. Essentially if I enter a bad url such as example.com/xyz I get the 404 page, however if I enter example.com/blog/xyz I just get a blank page.

I have checked for HTML content on this blank page - however it is completely void of anything!

I can't seem to find any settings that could override the blogs 404 settings in this way.

I have tried :

```
{if no_results} {redirect="404"} {/if}
```

Which I have seen on a few answers here, but this does not work either.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `require_entry = "yes"` parameter in the channel entries tag?

More info: https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_entries.html#require-entry

Comment: Hi @user1365655, yes this is in the channel entries tag but unfortunately not working.

Comment: Can you post an example of your channel entries tag code?